# Problem installing ubuntu 12.04..stuck at install screen

Tags: installation, windows

while trying to install ubuntu 12.04 after putting my wi-fi code in and press continue it doesent do anything the curser turns in to the ball that spins and doesent do anything else...i left it for 2 hours and still nothing :(

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you. Please look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 0):

During installing, do not connect to internet via WIFI or any other source. When you are connected to internet, it might be trying to update as well. Choose replace windows and try to install, but do not click anywhere which is written as connect to a network or something like that. You should be able to install. Please try this without being connected to internet. If the problem persists , Please leave a comment. And you don't need to provide any WIFI code. make sure you are not connected to any network or internet during installation.

Hope this helps, else ask again with your problem with details.       Thanks

Comment: i have windows 7 but windows wont boot so i want to replace it with ubuntu.so i dont want windows i only want ubuntu

Comment: Are u trying to install ubuntu with wubi_installer ? Do you have a copy of Ubuntu 12.04 ? If you have a copy, than it is easier and takes between 15 to 30 mins to install. If you are trying to install using internet, than you should check your internet speed. Please clarify, if you have a copy or not ? It is better to have a copy though. Please reply ASAP. Thanks

Comment: ok i have a copy burned on a cd which is what im using to install it.I cant use the wubi installer because i cant even boot windows so windows is broken or something.So to sum it up i am not trying to instal using wubi because that is not possible and i do have a copy of 12.04